# How do I reset the difficulty for an instrument path?

Tags: rocksmith-2014

In RockSmith 2014, I started by playing bass for a few days. The game quickly adapted to my skill level, becoming challenging but not frustrating. Then I switched to the lead guitar path, and was surprised to see a slew of unfamiliar chords thrown at me right off the bat. Apparently the game assumes that I must be as good with a six-string as I am with a bass!

Is there some way to tell the game to ease up a bit, short of deleting my profile entirely? I know that I can adjust the difficulty of individual songs via Riff Repeater, but doing that for every song would be tedious.

Comment: If all else fails, I assume you could just let it run for a while without playing? :)

Comment: This makes me wonder if it would be be better to create different profiles for different paths rather than trying to switch paths within a single profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, you cannot do this except for every single song with the riff repeater.

Comment: Yes, at this point I'm convinced that this is correct. The steep difficulty became more comfortable for me once I started taking advantage of the Rocksmith Recommends items (e.g. looking at the diagrams for each chord used in the song).

Answer (score 0):

If you go into riff repeater, select the entire song, reduce the level to what you want it to be, then hit "resume song" the song will stay at that level, at least for the current playthrough. Ive used this trick whenever I get lazy and dont play for a long time and forget certain songs.